# UIView bringSubviewToFront Breaks AutoLayout for UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a rather simple screen where I am inserting a custom UINavigationBar at the top of the screen and a content area below it. I'm using AutoLayout and I'm visually declaring the relationship as so:

```
@"V:|-0-[_navBar(65)]-0-[_content]-0-|";
```

Now, this seems to work perfectly until I tried to have another view slide down from under the navigation bar. The nav bar contains a search field and I want the search results to slide down from under nav bar. As the code currently stands, the search results slide down on top of or in front of the nav bar and it looks quite strange. So I tried to push the nav bar to the top of the index stack using:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_navBar];
```

As far as the animation is concerned, it works perfectly. The search results no longer slide over the nav bar but they are in front of the content area. When the child of _content is a UIView it seems to be OK. However, when the child of _content is a UIScrollView, this seems to have introduced a 20px margin between the nav bar and the content area. Honestly, the space seems to be very close in size to the status bar although the nav bar has stayed the same height. I've tried bringing the nav bar to the front using many different techiniques but as soon as the nav bar and the content area are on different planes, it seems to break the autolayout constraint of 0px that is defined above.

[Here is a sample project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8314200/TestAutoLayout.zip) to show the bug. Look at the third item, "bringSubViewToFront bug".

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: add `_navBar.clipsToBounds = YES;` above `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_navBar];` . does this fix it? (that may be not the proper way to fix it, but I just want to try something.)

Comment: You should post the code for your animation. BTW, "V:|[_navBar(65)][_content]|" is equivalent to what you have -- if you want a 0 spacing you do not have to use "-0-"

Comment: @Michael, unfortunately that didn't seem to work.

Comment: hmm, then I have no idea what is going on...

Comment: @rdelmar, actually this space shows up before the animation ever occurs. As soon as bringSubviewToFront is called, that space is inserted. I only mentioned the animation so that people wouldn't question why I was trying to place the nav bar at the top.

Comment: I don't see any white space added when I tried this. I think you need to provide more detail. How are you creating and adding the navigation bar and content view?

Comment: @rdelmar I've edited the original post to include a link to download a sample project that shows off the bug. In doing so I realized that this is only an issue when the content area is showing a UIScrollView.  It's as if the bringViewToFront command is forcing some sort of content padding to be introduced.

Look at Detail3ViewController.m and comment out the [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_navBar]; line. You'll see the gap of white disappear.

Answer (score 1):

The 20 point space seems like it would have something to do with the `status bar`, but I'm not sure why bringing the `navigation bar` to the front would apparently cause the scroll view to inset its content. Anyway, I was able to fix it by adding this line, after you bring the navigation bar to the front,

```
_scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems like a bit of a hack but it may be the only workaround because this may be a bug. I would hate to add this code in every screen in my app but again, this might be the only way. I'm going to hold off for a few days and see if anyone can find a different answer. If no one else does, I'll accept your answer and file a bug with Apple. Thanks again.

Comment: You know what's strange? If I just add another random view to self.view, even without attaching it to anything, the gap disappears.  Just add this and the gap goes away: [self.view addSubview:[[UIView alloc] init]];